# TypeError when working on a Minimax algorithm with tuples and floats

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm currently working on a project where I need to implement a Minimax algorithm to create a tic-tac-toe game. At some point I'm comparing tuples and floats, and while I know this can't actually be done, I don't know where that problem comes from or how do I fix it. If anyone could help me understand that would be amazing. Thanks!

Here's my code

```
import copy

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    Xboard_count = board[0].count(X) + board[1].count(X) + board[2].count(X)
    if Xboard_count % 2 == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return X



def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    move = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                move.append((i, j))

    return move


def result(board, move):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    if move not in actions(board):
        raise Exception("this action is not a valid action")

    dcopb = copy.deepcopy(board)
    dcopb[move[0]][move[1]] = player(board)

    return dcopb


def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """
    for x in range(3):
        if board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board[x][2] != EMPTY:
            return board[x][0]
    for y in range(3):
        if board[0][y] == board[1][y] == board[2][y] != EMPTY:
            return board[0][y]
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != EMPTY:
        return board[0][0]
    if board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2] != EMPTY:
        return board[2][0]
    else:
        return None


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return True
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return True

    for x in range(3):
        for y in range(3):
            if board[x][y] is None:
                return False
    return True
    ('si winner est égal à X :\n'
     '            return True\n'
     '        si winner est égal à 0\n'
     '            return true \n'
     '            \n'
     '        si le nombre de cases vides == 0\n'
     '            return true\n'
     '        else:\n'
     '            return false')


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return 1
    if winner(board) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    if terminal(board):
        return None

    if player(board) == X:
        v = v = float('-inf')
        for move in actions(board):
            temp = MinValue(result(board, move))
            if temp > v:
                v = temp
                best = move
    else:
        v = float('inf')
        for move in actions(board):
            temp = MaxValue(result(board, move))
            if temp < v:
                v = temp
                best = move
    return best
    

def MaxValue(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board), None

    v = float('-inf')
    for move in actions(board):
        v = max(v, MinValue(result(board, move)))
    return


def MinValue(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board), None

    v = float('inf')

    for move in actions(board):
        v = min(v, MaxValue(result(board, move)))
    return v
```

I get this exact error message

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'

Comment: You should be getting a stacktrace with that error message, and that stacktrace should tell you where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there was a problem with the MinValue and MaxValue function, they were sometimes returning two values instead of one.

Then, there was the same TypeError, this time with a problem when comparing NoneType variables with floats. Turns out there was just a small mistake because my MaxValue function wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a tuple at `return utility(board), None` in `MinValue`. So when you call the function at `temp = MinValue(result(board, move))`, `temp` is a tuple if that return statement was invoked

`v` is a float. Now when you try to compare it with `temp` at `if temp < v:`, you're comparing a float with a tuple

Comment: thank you, I have already figured that out, but now I'm getting this error with NoneType instead of tuple, like this File "/home/mrnb/Search//tictactoe.py", line 145, in MinValue
    v = min(v, value)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: Your function must be returning a `None` instead of a number. Try printing the return value